# Postfix: deliver mail in order

Tags: debian, postfix

I’ve got a setup where ordering of eMails matters (passing commit messages to a Fediverse client which converts them to Markdown and posts them).

On the sending side, I have my `sendmail` set up to retain the order:

```
define(`confQUEUE_SORT_ORDER', `time')dnl
```

This results in…

```
O QueueSortOrder=time
```

… in the resulting `sendmail.cf` file.

Now the recipient side is Postfix on Debian, which then uses a script using `python3-mastodon` to post, triggered like this in `/etc/aliases`:

```
foouser: |/usr/local/libexec/fooscript
```

However, incoming mails are not delivered to `foouser` in incoming order (the sending sendmail batches messages and sends them every couple of minutes, so this problem occurs when two (or more) eMails are sent to `foouser` in the same SMTP connection.

How can I configure Postfix to retain order for message delivery whenever possible, too? (I’m mostly a `sendmail` user, that’s why I wouldn’t know.)

Comment: (out of personal interest, your question is clear enough) Why, though? You got a UTC-translatable `Date:` header where the sending side tells you a date arguably more useful than the time of your eventual receipt, and you got an ideally globally-unique `Message-ID` headers to produce a stable sort order in case multiple messages are generated using the same timestamp of some underlying event.

Comment: @anx because when posting, it always uses the current date, I cannot backdate the post (or haven’t found the option), so I’d at least keep the order

Comment: I feel like this is incorrect problem. No mail standard I can cite that requires a software to maintain this order. Therefore, software is absolutely free to reorder. Also, there is no guarantee on the limit of delay of messages; if first-composed arrives a minute later than second one, that's totally fine. You have to use artificial in-message metadata to guarantee order of processing and to avoid skipping delayed messages ("jitter" so to speak), the suggested `Date:` header is a start. Just don't expect such functionality to exist in the MTA and even it seems to be there, don't rely on it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov as I already wrote, `sendmail` can be configured to send it first, and I had the question whether Postfix can also be configured. (Turns out it probably can.) Yes, this is not in the SMTP standard, but extensions are definitely allowed, and I just want “best effort”. Sure, if the delivery of the first message is delayed, I lose, but in _normal_ operation it won’t. Please don’t apply your preconceived opinions about what problems people are allowed to have, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even the "new" postfix queue manager - within a single destination - is documented to deliver in the expected order:

> that is, FIFO unless there was some preemption involved -- [SCHEDULER_README.html](https://www.postfix.org/SCHEDULER_README.html)

You want to look at these settings for globally disabling the default concurrency (multiple threads) and preemption (out of order) mechanism:

```postconf
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
default_delivery_slot_cost = 0
```

Mind `man 5 postconf` notes on configuring these per-transport. Which you want, if that server is also processing other mail, turning off both globally would be wasteful.

Comment: oic, the config has `default_destination_concurrency_limit = 4` currently; I’ll see if I can override that for… local, I suppose. (I cannot do that for just that one account, right? Too bad… oh wait, actual local accounts use the `tmail` transport from UW mailutils, so that should work well. Or do I need `pipe`?

Comment: @mirabilos I did not write add that in the answer, because I have not tested, and have been wrong about a different option before. I *suspect* you can do it for just one accounts: add a (renamed) copy of your existing transport to your `master.cf`, add ` -o option=value` overrides below, then redirect that specific destination there via transport_maps.

Comment: hmm, from the postconf manpage, I *thought* I would need `pipe_destination_concurrency_limit = 1` and `pipe_destination_recipient_limit = 1` but that doesn’t seem to be correct (`postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter`)

Comment: oic, I need xxx_ where xxx is the LHS of a thing in master.cf but pipe is an RHS, not LHS… so I need to figure out which transport is used for these (from the `relay=local` in syslog, probably local?)

Comment: @mirabilos Is your *transport* really named `pipe` ;) That is the name of the used daemon processes, but ideally would would have given it a more verbose name. The first column in [master.cf](https://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) - (edit) yes, sounds good.